# Where do I hook to have the server do something in PHP on block attribute change?

Tags: plugin-development, actions, block-editor

I'm creating a new block plugin, and I'd like the server to do some stuff when certain attributes change. I'm thinking I'm looking for something like

```
function my_attribute_changed ( $block_ID, $attribute, $value ) {
        // do some stuff
}
add_action('gutenberg-attribute-change', 'my_attribute_changed', 10, 3);
```

but I'm not seeing any such thing in the docs, and am thinking maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree, so to speak.

**Context**
I imagine there are lots of reasons one may want to do such a thing, but in this particular instance, the block's edit function has an attribute that is a URL that points to a 3rd party API. My plan is set a wp_cron to grab the data at regular intervals, and store it in transient. Then the block's save function will grab that transient data via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood exactly your goal, but check if hooking to [render_block](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/render_block/) does what you want, as it will modify the block's output before it gets rendered in the frontend. Usage example:

```
add_filter( 'render_block', 'my_dynamic_data', 10, 2 );

function my_dynamic_data( $block_content, $block ) {

    if('my_value' === $block['attrs']['myAttribute'] ) {
       // Do something
    }   

    return $block_content;
}
```